# Django admin particular data for particular user

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin

I am using django admin site to let people manage database easier.

For some reason, I want to hide some data from some user.

Let's say I have a model named Book and there are a lot of books in database. I want different user has the different scope of books he can view.

How would I do that?

I am thinking about permission. Is that possible to set the permission to filter the data?

I know how to create permission according to a specified model. However, after that, how do I suppose to use that permission? I believe I may need to override part of "changelist_view" method under BookAdmin class, right?

Any help would works. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `queryset` method on your admin model.  Something like:

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def queryset(self, request):
        return super(BookAdmin, self).queryset(request).filter(owner=request.user)
```

Obviously the filter will vary depending on your book model, but this is the general idea.

Comment: This is much easier, I think. I will give a try see whether it works or not.

Comment: BTW, I will give the "accept" after I finished testing stuff. And that may take a while.